# Decoding in Ruby using base64

Tags: ruby, binary, base64, decode

How I can decode the following binary 64 bit float?

> 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

Using the Base64.decode64('insert above binary data here') returns this following mess

> �F�pHf�FnHP�G:�G�3GdW�F��G1��FyG�
>   JG�>GnJ�F[o�G�vG��G�^;H�k
>   ��F�B�F0�   G���F���F�`?G��Ge��GL��F})�F�S�F�A�F"A�F��F3�F�F�C�Ft:G�QG �Fx܊F.iG�׭Fl�F44qGgɰF��MGuP�H/�#G���FU
>   �G*�Fa��F

I need to decode it to a list of floats like this
27489.1602
57338.4453
45343.3516
91321.0391
43205.043
and so on....

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think more information is needed to decode the string. The byte order is unknown, nor is the byte length. Once the string is decoded - I used `s.unpack('m*')[0]` - the unpacking of the string requires more information. For example, `s.unpack('m*')[0].unpack('d*')` is different than `s.unpack('m*')[0].unpack('f*')` ... Please provide more information.

Comment: 64bit float, 1824 is encodedLength, no compression... I don't know what you are asking for but this is all the information I have to decode it.

Comment: `s.unpack('m*')[0]` decodes the Base64 (it's the same as `Base64.decode64(s)`), but now we have a string we want to [`#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack), converting the bit sequence into new objects. The bit sequence holds 1368 bytes (once Base64 was decoded), which packs 171 64bit sequences.... I think maybe this is what you are looking for: `s.unpack('m*')[0].unpack('d*')` ... only I don't get the values in your example, so I must be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `s.unpack('m*')[0]` to decode the Base64 string.

it's the same as: `Base64.decode64(s)`

Now we have a string we want to [`#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack), converting the bit sequence into new objects.

The bit sequence holds 1368 bytes (once Base64 was decoded), which packs 171 64bit sequences.... I think maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
s.unpack('m*')[0].unpack('d*')
# => [595.6329345703125, 596.281005859375, 596.529296875, ... ]
```

... only I don't get the values in your example, so I must be wrong.